# Total Donations By Contact

Tags: civicontribute, civireport

I am looking to pull a report that has the donation total for each contact.  Basically the top donor report but for all donors.

What report will give this to me.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 2):

If you leave the filter called **Show no. of Top Donors** empty then you will get a list of all contacts and their donation totals.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the extension [summary fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) - which provides a number of additional information regarding contributions including "lifetime donations".